# Is HINSTANCE valid across threads?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In a single .exe application `WinMain` entry point has an `HINSTANCE` parameter which should be a pseudo-handle (because equivalent to `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` which returns a pseudo-handle, according to MSDN). I suppose it's *pseudo* because there are both *special values* (such as `NULL` to mean entry-point module) and constants used to return an error (anything less than 32).

MSDN explicitly describes it as a *pointer* (nowadays equivalent to an `HMODULE`) to module base address; we know this may have a completely different meaning for 16 bit applications but in 32/64 bits world each process has its own address space then its *exact* value is useless, probably always the same for each instance and absolutely meaningless outside its process.

All these said, this is my **first question**: can we (formally, despite MSDN seems to be contradictory) assume `HINSTANCE` is a pointer (even if honestly I don't see any use for this) or it's better assume it's a (pseudo) handle (where its value is *opaque*)?

Let's assume it's value is opaque, my **second question**: is its value valid per-process or per-thread?

We may think a process handle is valid per-process but few (corner) cases make me think we should assume it's valid per-thread. If these corner cases exist then (even if usually it seems to work *as expected* per-process) we're relying on an implementation detail, an *undefined behavior* subject to change for different architectures, versions, environments.

Let's see a case where I see an issue (code is so trivial that I just describe scenario): DLLs has usually a shared code section but they may also have (even if it's pretty uncommon) a shared data section (for example to share *expansive* data across processes or to implement a quick-and-dirty IPC mechanism). It may be uncommon but possible (and pretty easy to implement, for example in VC++, with few `#pragma`s `data_seg` and `comment(linker)` directives). In this case we're aware (inside our DLL) that we can't compare `HINSTANCE`s (because they may have same value) but also IMO we can't *trust* `HINSTANCE` we had from thread A (within our DLL) is *comparable* to `HINSTANCE` we have in thread B. In short: each time we need an `HINSTANCE` we have to call `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` to get *actual* per-thread valid one.

As **bonus** I would also understand how this applies to `HINSTANCE` we get as parameter when it comes from `WinMain`. In theory it's per-thread but, for example, `CreateWindow()` will resolve it correctly (because scope is *current executing process*, of course assuming calling thread has its own message loop)?

```
void createToolbox(const char* windowName, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    // ...

    // Do we need this?
    // HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    CreateWindow(windowClass, windowName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 640, 480,
        0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    // ...
}
```

**EDIT** it seems I was completely wrong, I did remember thread affinity for HMODULE but it applies to **Windows Mobile**...

> If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleHandle returns a pseudo handle to the current process. [...] A pseudo handle is a special constant that is interpreted as the current thread handle. The calling thread can use this handle to specify itself when a thread handle is required.

Obviously this isn't true for desktop applications (among other differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module in the process has a module handle that is also the base address of that module. The `hInstance` argument passed to `WinMain` is the base address of the main module of the process. As such, it is valid throughout the process because the process has a single virtual address space.

It is always the case that the `hInstance` argument passed to `WinMain` is equal to `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.

You can usually treat module handles as opaque if you wish. That is, you don't generally need to de-reference the pointer and simply pass it along to API functions that require `HMODULE` arguments. None of that changes whether or not the value is valid in different threads. The value is a per-process value.

I cannot make any sense of your bonus question. I suspect that stems from a mistake assumption that module handles are per-thread. Once you accept that a module handle has the same meaning in all threads within a process, the vast majority of your question dissolves.

Comment: I agree about that in _normal_ life but (see second point of my prolix question) I doubt about it for some scenarios (and if _sometimes_ it's not valid then I _worry_ it's just an implementation detail and we're relying on an undefined behavior). Clarification: when I speak about HINSTANCE I mean entry-point one (I don't see any case where value from another module may not be valid per-process).

Comment: You seem deeply confused. Your clarification in that comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: You're right, I was completely confused about this (see latest edit to my question). What I thought it's a general rule...in reality applies to Windows Mobile only (and after first time I never checked GetModuleHandle again...)

Comment: OK, that's good. I'm still wondering why my answer attracted a down vote. Perhaps somebody else was confused!

Comment: For sure I can't blame them, obviously for me it was all but clear. I should really accept _all_ answers (because I finally managed to recheck my _source_ when everyone told me I was d*** wrong) but you have been first to post!

Answer (score 2):

A [HINSTANCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) is documented as:

> A handle to an instance. This is the base address of the module in memory.

The `hInstance` parameter passed to `WinMain` is the base address of the module used to create the process. It is valid throughout the lifetime of a process. Since it is a pointer, it doesn't have thread affinity, and can be freely passed between threads. In fact, this pointer already exists before the OS has created a single thread in a process.

The *"special values"* are not a property of the `HINSTANCE` data type. They are part of the contract of [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx):

> The return value is cast as an HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications. It is not a true HINSTANCE, however.

Bonus reading: [What can I do with the HINSTANCE returned by the ShellExecute function?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/05/590749.aspx)

Comment: My upvote, you're right, I was completely confused about this (see latest edit to my question). What I thought it's a general rule...in reality applies to Windows Mobile only (and after first time I never checked GetModuleHandle again...)

Answer (score 1):

I see no mention anywhere in MSDN of `GetModuleHandle()` ever returning a pseudo-handle in any circumstances (unlike `GetCurrentProcess()`/`GetCurrentThread()`). Therefore, there is no such thing as thread affinity for module handles. They're all process-wide, which is specifically why `GetModuleHandle()`'s documentation warns about threading issues.

Being a pointer to the module's base address only confirms it, for the reasons you evoked.

So, to your first question, I answer it's safe to assume them to be pointers if they are documented to be so. Otherwise, it's *always* safe treat them as **opaque** handles, and know they are never **pseudo** handles.

To your second question, I confirm it's per-process.

To your scenario, I say since `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is useless from a DLL, the simplest way is to store the module handle passed to `DllMain()` in a non-shared global variable for this DLL.

As for your bonus question, yes it would work.

*I have no idea what led you to believe module handles had thread affinity.*

Comment: You're right, I was completely confused about this (see latest edit to my question). What I thought it's a general rule...in reality applies to Windows Mobile only (and after first time I never checked GetModuleHandle again...)